# Java JTable Checkbox in header

Tags: java, jtable, jtableheader

I am working on placing a CheckBox in the header columns of a JTable. I have gotten them to render in the table header, however, they are not clickable. I have tried implementing an ItemListener, ActionListener, and MouseListener to listen for the click events, however, none of them work as far as receiving the click event. Here is my code that does the displaying of the JTable:

```
    public void loadTable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 3);        
        for(int outter = 0; outter < 5; outter++) { // Rows
            model.addRow(adcSamples.get(outter).toArray());
        } 
        jTableCSV.setModel(model);
        
        // Set the header cell renderer for each column
        TableColumnModel columnModel = jTableCSV.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(i);            
            column.setHeaderRenderer(new CheckBoxHeaderRenderer(i));
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that implements TableCellRenderer to help display the CheckBox's in the header columns:

```
public class CheckBoxHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private final JCheckBox checkBox;
    private JTable table;
    
    public CheckBoxHeaderRenderer(int columnIndex) {
        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        // Set text based on the column index or your logic here
        checkBox.setText("Column " + (columnIndex + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        this.table = table;
        
        return checkBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JTables don't work with subcomponents (though they do use them for rendering)

Right here (see where my comment is):

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    this.table = table;
    // you need to get the data at the row and the column. 
    //If the data indicates that the checkbox should be checked, 
    // you should check the checkbox
    return checkBox;
}
```

Also use a TableCellEditor to change the value in your TableModel on click. If this is not what you want, then forget the JTable and use a JPanel with a GridLayout instead. Or better yet, create your own JComponent to handle this. Or better still, don't use Swing/Java, which is now outdated. Use HTML 5 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Those help greatly!